# How do I create a packed data structure in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm converting a project from Objective-C to Swift, and I'm using a packed struct to type cast binary messages sent over a socket:

```c
typedef struct {
    uint16_t version;  // Message format version, currently 0x0100.
    uint32_t length;   // Length of data in bytes.
    uint16_t reserved; // Reserved for future use.
    uint8_t data[];    // Binary encoded plist.
} __attribute__((packed)) mma_msg_t;
```

I'm not sure what the best approach is in Swift, and the closest approximation I can get is:

```
struct mma_msg {
    var version: CUnsignedShort     // Message format version, currently 0x0100.
    var length: CUnsignedInt        // Length of data in bytes.
    var reserved: CUnsignedShort    // Reserved for future use.
    var data: CUnsignedChar[]       // Binary encoded plist.
}
```

Two important details are lost in the translation: there's no guaranteed bitsize of the integer types, and there's no structure packing. I don't think this can be expressed in Swift, but if so, how?

I'm open to suggestions of an alternative approach, e.g. something along the lines of Python's `struct` module.

Comment: why you want packed structure in Swift? Swift is high level language, which should handle all these details for you. if you need it for C/ObjC code, they should be declared in C header and atomically translated by compiler to Swift code when you import it

Comment: As I mention in the last sentence I'm looking for an alternative approach to generating packed binary data.

Comment: but there is no reason to do it. or you can provide a reason?

Comment: BTW, you can use `UInt16` `UInt8` etc which guaranteed bitsize of the integer types

Comment: I need to send a packed binary message over a socket. In my Python code I create the header with struct.pack("HHI", 0x0100, 0, len(reply)), but I need the equivalent in Swift.

Comment: write your own serialization code. construct `NSMutableData` with given size, and fill the memory yourself. you can't `memcpy` the struct anyway

Comment: This is precisely what I want to avoid :)

Comment: I am pretty sure someone will write some struct module like python in Swift. I can see it is very useful. Maybe you can start writing it :)

Comment: Trying to do similar things in high level languages is disgusting. Find a Java solution first, I dare you!

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate question to ask...no need to pester the OP.

Comment: This is a pretty cool idea, I'm going to try my hand at replicating the Python `struct.pack()` function.

Comment: "can provide a reason?" If nothing else, curiosity and a better understanding of the language are worthy reasons, imho.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I started writing a Swift class modeled after Python's struct module, it can be found on github as [MVPCStruct](https://github.com/MagerValp/MVPCStruct).

Code for the first prototype was as follows:

```
enum Endianness {
    case littleEndian
    case bigEndian
}

// Split a large integer into bytes.
extension Int {
    func splitBytes(endianness: Endianness, size: Int) -> UInt8[] {
        var bytes = UInt8[]()
        var shift: Int
        var step: Int
        if endianness == .littleEndian {
            shift = 0
            step = 8
        } else {
            shift = (size - 1) * 8
            step = -8
        }
        for count in 0..size {
            bytes.append(UInt8((self >> shift) & 0xff))
            shift += step
        }
        return bytes
    }
}
extension UInt {
    func splitBytes(endianness: Endianness, size: Int) -> UInt8[] {
        var bytes = UInt8[]()
        var shift: Int
        var step: Int
        if endianness == .littleEndian {
            shift = 0
            step = 8
        } else {
            shift = Int((size - 1) * 8)
            step = -8
        }
        for count in 0..size {
            bytes.append(UInt8((self >> UInt(shift)) & 0xff))
            shift = shift + step
        }
        return bytes
    }
}


class Struct: NSObject {

    //class let PAD_BYTE = UInt8(0x00)    // error: class variables not yet supported
    //class let ERROR_PACKING = -1

    class func platformEndianness() -> Endianness {
        return .littleEndian
    }

    // Pack an array of data according to the format string. Return NSData
    // or nil if there's an error.
    class func pack(format: String, data: AnyObject[], error: NSErrorPointer) -> NSData? {
        let PAD_BYTE = UInt8(0x00)
        let ERROR_PACKING = -1

        var bytes = UInt8[]()
        var index = 0
        var repeat = 0
        var alignment = true
        var endianness = Struct.platformEndianness()

        // Set error message and return nil.
        func failure(message: String) -> NSData? {
            if error {
                error.memory = NSError(domain: "se.gu.it.GUStructPacker",
                    code: ERROR_PACKING,
                    userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: message])
            }
            return nil
        }

        // If alignment is requested, emit pad bytes until alignment is
        // satisfied.
        func padAlignment(size: Int) {
            if alignment {
                let mask = size - 1
                while (bytes.count & mask) != 0 {
                    bytes.append(PAD_BYTE)
                }
            }
        }

        for c in format {
            // Integers are repeat counters. Consume and continue.
            if let value = String(c).toInt() {
                repeat = repeat * 10 + value
                continue
            }
            // Process repeat count values, minimum of 1.
            for i in 0..(repeat > 0 ? repeat : 1) {
                switch c {

                case "@":
                    endianness = Struct.platformEndianness()
                    alignment = true
                case "=":
                    endianness = Struct.platformEndianness()
                    alignment = false
                case "<":
                    endianness = Endianness.littleEndian
                    alignment = false
                case ">":
                    endianness = Endianness.bigEndian
                    alignment = false
                case "!":
                    endianness = Endianness.bigEndian
                    alignment = false

                case "x":
                    bytes.append(PAD_BYTE)

                default:

                    if index >= data.count {
                        return failure("expected at least \(index) items for packing, got \(data.count)")
                    }
                    let rawValue: AnyObject = data[index++]

                    switch c {

                    case "c":
                        if let str = rawValue as? String {
                            let codePoint = str.utf16[0]
                            if codePoint < 128 {
                                bytes.append(UInt8(codePoint))
                            } else {
                                return failure("char format requires String of length 1")
                            }
                        } else {
                            return failure("char format requires String of length 1")
                        }

                    case "b":
                        if let value = rawValue as? Int {
                            if value >= -0x80 && value <= 0x7f {
                                bytes.append(UInt8(value & 0xff))
                            } else {
                                return failure("value outside valid range of Int8")
                            }
                        } else {
                            return failure("cannot convert argument to Int")
                        }

                    case "B":
                        if let value = rawValue as? UInt {
                            if value > 0xff {
                                return failure("value outside valid range of UInt8")
                            } else {
                                bytes.append(UInt8(value))
                            }
                        } else {
                            return failure("cannot convert argument to UInt")
                        }

                    case "?":
                        if let value = rawValue as? Bool {
                            if value {
                                bytes.append(UInt8(1))
                            } else {
                                bytes.append(UInt8(0))
                            }
                        } else {
                            return failure("cannot convert argument to Bool")
                        }

                    case "h":
                        if let value = rawValue as? Int {
                            if value >= -0x8000 && value <= 0x7fff {
                                padAlignment(2)
                                bytes.extend(value.splitBytes(endianness, size: 2))
                            } else {
                                return failure("value outside valid range of Int16")
                            }
                        } else {
                            return failure("cannot convert argument to Int")
                        }

                    case "H":
                        if let value = rawValue as? UInt {
                            if value > 0xffff {
                                return failure("value outside valid range of UInt16")
                            } else {
                                padAlignment(2)
                                bytes.extend(value.splitBytes(endianness, size: 2))
                            }
                        } else {
                            return failure("cannot convert argument to UInt")
                        }

                    case "i", "l":
                        if let value = rawValue as? Int {
                            if value >= -0x80000000 && value <= 0x7fffffff {
                                padAlignment(4)
                                bytes.extend(value.splitBytes(endianness, size: 4))
                            } else {
                                return failure("value outside valid range of Int32")
                            }
                        } else {
                            return failure("cannot convert argument to Int")
                        }

                    case "I", "L":
                        if let value = rawValue as? UInt {
                            if value > 0xffffffff {
                                return failure("value outside valid range of UInt32")
                            } else {
                                padAlignment(4)
                                bytes.extend(value.splitBytes(endianness, size: 4))
                            }
                        } else {
                            return failure("cannot convert argument to UInt")
                        }

                    case "q":
                        if let value = rawValue as? Int {
                            padAlignment(8)
                            bytes.extend(value.splitBytes(endianness, size: 8))
                        } else {
                            return failure("cannot convert argument to Int")
                        }

                    case "Q":
                        if let value = rawValue as? UInt {
                            padAlignment(8)
                            bytes.extend(value.splitBytes(endianness, size: 8))
                        } else {
                            return failure("cannot convert argument to UInt")
                        }

                    case "f", "d":
                        assert(false, "float/double unimplemented")

                    case "s", "p":
                        assert(false, "cstring/pstring unimplemented")

                    case "P":
                        assert(false, "pointer unimplemented")

                    default:
                        return failure("bad character in format")
                    }
                }
            }
            // Reset the repeat counter.
            repeat = 0
        }

        if index != data.count {
            return failure("expected \(index) items for packing, got \(data.count)")
        }
        return NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count)
    }

}
```

Comment: Neat! This is the kind of stuff that makes Swift pretty fun.

Comment: Holy crap, what an answer! Really like what you did with that, pretty much perfectly lines up with PHP's [pack](http://php.net/pack) function

Comment: You forgot the middle endians :)

Answer (score 8):

I decided to try this out since it seemed fun so I came up with a solution for `struct.pack(...)`.

You can also enforce bit-size on integers in your struct:

```
struct MyMessage
{
    var version : UInt16
    var length : UInt32
    var reserved : UInt16
    var data : UInt8[]
}
```

Now on to the packed structures...

### Integer Extensions

```
    extension Int
    {
        func loByte() -> UInt8 { return UInt8(self & 0xFF) }
        func hiByte() -> UInt8 { return UInt8((self >> 8) & 0xFF) }
        func loWord() -> Int16 { return Int16(self & 0xFFFF) }
        func hiWord() -> Int16 { return Int16((self >> 16) & 0xFFFF) }
    }

    extension Int16
    {
        func loByte() -> UInt8 { return UInt8(self & 0xFF) }
        func hiByte() -> UInt8 { return UInt8((self >> 8) & 0xFF) }
    }

    extension UInt
    {
        func loByte() -> UInt8 { return UInt8(self & 0xFF) }
        func hiByte() -> UInt8 { return UInt8((self >> 8) & 0xFF) }
        func loWord() -> UInt16 { return UInt16(self & 0xFFFF) }
        func hiWord() -> UInt16 { return UInt16((self >> 16) & 0xFFFF) }
    }

    extension UInt16
    {
        func loByte() -> UInt8 { return UInt8(self & 0xFF) }
        func hiByte() -> UInt8 { return UInt8((self >> 8) & 0xFF) }
    }
```

### Data Packer

```
class DataPacker
{
    class func pack(format: String, values: AnyObject...) -> String?
    {
        var bytes = UInt8[]()
        var index = 0

        for char in format
        {
            let value : AnyObject! = values[index++]

            switch(char)
            {
                case "h":
                    bytes.append((value as Int).loByte())
                    bytes.append((value as Int).hiByte())
                case "H":
                    bytes.append((value as UInt).loByte())
                    bytes.append((value as UInt).hiByte())
                case "i":
                    bytes.append((value as Int).loWord().loByte())
                    bytes.append((value as Int).loWord().hiByte())
                    bytes.append((value as Int).hiWord().loByte())
                    bytes.append((value as Int).hiWord().hiByte())
                case "I":
                    bytes.append((value as UInt).loWord().loByte())
                    bytes.append((value as UInt).loWord().hiByte())
                    bytes.append((value as UInt).hiWord().loByte())
                    bytes.append((value as UInt).hiWord().hiByte())
                default:
                    println("Unrecognized character: \(char)")
            }
        }

        return String.stringWithBytes(bytes, length: bytes.count, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
    }
}
```

### Try It Out

```
let packedString = DataPacker.pack("HHI", values: 0x100, 0x0, 512)
println(packedString)
```

### Notes

This example is extremely simple and has no real error or type checking. Also, it does not really enforce any system byte-order (endianness) so that may be problematic. Hopefully this is somewhat a starting point for those interested.

For unpacking I did notice that Swift allowed returning a variable-sized tuple. For example: `func unpack(format: String) -> (AnyObject...)` did not give a compile warning. However, I have no idea how you'd return something like that.

Comment: I went and wrote my own class inspired by your solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/nst/BinUtils/

Akin to Python's struct.pack()

```
let d = pack("<h2I3sf", [1, 2, 3, "asd", 0.5])
assert(d == unhexlify("0100 02000000 03000000 617364 0000003f"))
```

Akin to Python's struct.unpack()

```
let a = unpack(">hBsf", unhexlify("0500 01 41 3fc00000")!)
assert(a[0] as? Int == 1280)
assert(a[1] as? Int == 1)
assert(a[2] as? String == "A")
assert(a[3] as? Double == 1.5)
```